# How to use each in rails to display values of an array

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I have a @keyword variable which holds the string "cat dog mouse bird"

I want to display the values of each word under a span element.

My algorithm looks like

```
<%= @keyword.split.each {|key| "<span>#{key}</span>".html_safe %>
```

but when viewing it, it displays an array of [cat dog mouse bird]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about programming

Comment: Should get a better answer here http://stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= @keyword.split.map {|key| "<span>#{key}</span>".html_safe }.join("\n") %>
```

Comment: Thanks man. By the way sorry, I thought this was stack overflow, work is taking a toll on my sanity.